# In php blade file Client tokens Vue components not showing

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport

In Laravel 5.7, Passport installation has no problem but I'm not getting the vue component view in my blade file

I've tried app.js import & paste all view components before new Vue. Run npm install, run npm dev, watch but none of them work. In 5.7 there is no asset folder though & it saves in resources/js/components

//------app.js -----------//

```
Vue.component(
    'passport-clients',
    require('./components/passport/Clients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-authorized-clients',
    require('./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue')
);

Vue.component(
    'passport-personal-access-tokens',
    require('./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue')
);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

//------token.blade.php ---//

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div id="app">
        <passport-clients></passport-clients>
        <passport-authorized-clients></passport-authorized-clients>
        <passport-personal-access-tokens></passport-personal-access-tokens>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue with laravel 8.x and resolved it as follows

1. Make sure your installed the appropriate frontend scafolding with the below commands:

> php artisan ui bootstrap and
> php artisan ui vue

2. Run the below commands:

> npm install and
> npm run dev

3. Follow the below syntax to define your view components:
   Vue.component(
   'example-component',
   require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default
   );
4. Include the vue component in your blade view file as follows:

@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')

```
<example-component></example-component>
```

@endsection

5. Recompile your vue components with the command:

> npm run dev